# Salesforce Analytics Cloud Query

Tags: analytics, analytics-cloud

Quick Question :

Can we use a unstructured document database (Mongo for eg) for Salesforce Analytics Cloud or does it work with only RDBMS ?

Answer (score 0):

You import datasets to it. Then basically run SUM, COUNT, etc on it.

You can later modify the views of it via JSON, but as far as I know there are no way to do queries.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Analytics Cloud as of today comes with native import option for 2 sources

- Salesforce Data,
- CSV Files

But for most other data sources (including on premise, cloud, structured, unstructured, nosql, document based, etc.. ) you can use 3rd party ETL tools like Informatica, Boomi, Mulesoft, etc..

you need to have the base ETL product and on top, you need to get the connectors for the source (say mongo db in your case) and target systems (analytics cloud)

here's some references on the connectors

[Mulesoft MongoDB Connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/mongodb-integration-connector?types=connector&sortBy=name)

[Mulesoft Analytics Cloud Connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/salesforce-analytics-cloud-integration-connector?types=connector&sortBy=name)

[List of Informatica Connectors](https://www.informatica.com/products/cloud-integration/connectivity/connectors.html)